# A learning application for popular web frameworks, like TodoMVC

Tags: frameworks, comparison, todomvc

First of all, to the moderators, don't get angry if this is not the right place to post this :).

I wondre if there is something like the [TodoMVC](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) for popular web frameworks like Django, Rails, Symfony and etc.

If there is not something like this, we could create one.

Any ideas? Volunteers?

Answer (score 3):

There is open source [notejam](https://github.com/komarserjio/notejam/) project. TodoMVC-like project for server-side frameworks (php, python, ruby are supported so far).

Comment: pitty they don't have "vanilla" PHP :D without any framework